# Teamcity Sonar runner plugin fails to query properties

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, teamcity-8.0

Looks like the new sonar runner plugin does not work with latest version of sonar(4.5). Does anyone know how to fix this?

It fails with the below error:

> [15:10:11][Step 3/3] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ERROR: Caused by: [15:10:11][Step 3/3] ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'properties'.[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ### The error may exist in org.sonar.core.properties.PropertiesMapper[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ### The error may involve org.sonar.core.properties.PropertiesMapper.selectByKey-Inline[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ### The error occurred while setting parameters[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ### SQL: select p.id as id, p.prop_key as "key", p.text_value as value, p.resource_id as resourceId, p.user_id as userId     from properties p     where p.prop_key=?             AND p.resource_id is null                         AND p.user_id is null[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'properties'.[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ERROR: Caused by: Invalid object name 'properties'.[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ERROR: [15:10:11][Step 3/3] ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.[15:10:11][Step 3/3] ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.[15:10:11][Step 3/3] Process exited with code 1[15:10:11][Step 3/3] Step SonarQube Runner failed
>
> Stack:
>        Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: [14:54:33][Step 3/3] ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'properties'.[14:54:33][Step 3/3] ### The error may exist in org.sonar.core.properties.PropertiesMapper[14:54:33][Step 3/3] ### The error may involve org.sonar.core.properties.PropertiesMapper.selectByKey-Inline[14:54:33][Step 3/3] ### The error occurred while setting parameters[14:54:33][Step 3/3] ### SQL: select p.id as id, p.prop_key as "key", p.text_value as value, p.resource_id as resourceId, p.user_id as userId from properties p     where p.prop_key=? AND p.resource_id is null AND p.user_id is null[14:54:33][Step 3/3] ### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'properties'.